# Removing all INPUT DROP rules I've created so far

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables

I am trying to create a script that will ban certain IP addresses under certain conditions and I need a way to sort of "clear" the blocks each midnight, to start over. I have created the blocking part with success.

I am now trying to **remove all INPUT DROP rules at once**, but the following command returns "bad rule" error.

```
iptables -D INPUT -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method to work around the problem so it doesn't exist at all. Instead of adding drop rules in filter/INPUT:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.0.2.2 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 198.51.100.10 -i eth0 -j DROP
...
```

create a dedicated user chain to help manage these drop rules. Do this once:

```
iptables -N onlydrops
iptables -A INPUT -j onlydrops
```

Then whenever needed:

```
iptables -A onlydrops -s 192.0.2.2 -j DROP
iptables -A onlydrops -s 198.51.100.10 -i eth0 -j DROP
...
```

When this is done, all of the user chain content can be flushed in one command, without affecting the remaining ruleset in INPUT. At midnight one can just run:

```
iptables -F onlydrops
```

As usual order does matter. Above is just an example to be tailored to the use case and existing rules.

Comment: You saved my day and you contributed to my iptables understanding, big time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of iptables is that you cannot remove a set of rules (e.g. all DROP rules) with one invocation of the "-D" command.

You can drop all rules from a chain, with Flush (-F).
You can drop a single rule from a chain, with Delete (-D).

The following question and answer shows that this is even a problem when your rule entries are identical:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25055121/can-i-remove-multiple-matching-rules-with-the-iptables-delete-command

In my opinion, the man page for iptabels, where it mentions

> Delete one or more rules from the selected chain

is misleading. I don't know of a case where multiple rules can be deleted from a single invocation from `iptables -D`.  However, maybe there are some cases where this is possible that I'm not aware of.

UPDATE: See the comment from A.B, where it is pointed out that DNS can play a role with removing multiple rules with the "-D" parameter.  That's in the case where a DNS name resolves to multiple IPs.

Comment: When DNS resolution converts a single DNS name into multiple IP addresses, the command is then duplicated to add (-A or -I) or remove (-D) these multiple rules each having one different IP address. As it's probably bad practice to use DNS in iptables rules, this doesn't happen often. This is not OP's case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your iptables rules don't have newline characters in their definition¹, you should be able to do:

```
iptables-save -t filter | grep -vxe '-A INPUT .*-j DROP' | iptables-restore
```

To remove the rules that start with `-A INPUT` and end in `-j DROP` in the `iptables-save` output.

---

<sup>¹ but I find that even `iptables-restore` can't deal with `iptables-save` output if they do, which I'd consider a bug.</sup>